# Importing a file from a local funtion in typescript return error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import

When I try to import a file like this

```js
let files = (fs.readdirSync("./commands"))

  files.forEach(file => {
    import command from `../commands/${file}`

    console.log( command )
  })
```

I get error like this

```js
> handler/index.ts:14:11: error: Unexpected "command"
    14 │     import command from `../commands/${file}`
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: OK then. How do I import files after runtime ? @pussam

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
import command from `../commands/${file}`
```

to

```
import command from `./commands/${file}`
```

Comment: Bro I don't see any difference

Comment: Want to read a subdirectory?

Comment: Yeah After runtime

Comment: try this import {command } from `./commands/${file}` or import {command } from `../commands/${file}`

Comment: Use curly brackets and then give me a response pls.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: The real problem is that `import` key word does not work after runtime , an when I try `require("./commands/"+file)` or `require("../commands/"+ file)` it says there is no such file or directory like that .

Comment: Did u try to use require() ?

Comment: I just said that I tried "require" and did not worked